# Update only first row of pandas dataframe in every iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating over pandas dataframe where on a given condition it selects a subset of dataframe. On the selected dataframe I want to update on first row of a specific column

I have tried with replace method of pandas but it replaces everything. I just want to update first row and nothing else

```
for unique_master_pr in same_date_PR_unique:
    dataframe_from_master = pr_event_data_copy[pr_event_data_copy['PR'] == unique_master_pr].reset_index(drop=True)

    temp_frame  = dataframe_from_master['t_code'].iloc[0].replace('Change Purchase Requisition', 'Create Purchase Requisition')
    print(temp_frame)
```

Input :

```
PR number   Tcode
  PR1     change PR
  PR1     change PR
```

Output :

```
PR number   Tcode
  PR1     create PR
  PR1     change PR
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am iterating over pandas dataframe where on a **given condition it selects a subset of dataframe**. On the selected dataframe I want to **update on first row of a specific column**

To accomplish this:

- **Create a subset of dataframe:**

`new_df = original_df[original_df["condition_col"]==unique_master_pr]`

- **Update first row of a specific column**

`new_df.iloc[0, specific_col_number] = updated_value`

*Note, I'm not sure this is the most efficient method to achieve your outcome, but I would need more information on the problem to optimize it further.*

Answer (score 1):

One of the way

```
dataframe_from_master['Tcode'].iloc[0] = "create PR"
```

Comment: This method fails in case `index` does not start from `0`